# Is it bad to delete records in this fashion with data adapter?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I was wondering if there were any consquesnces to doing it this way.

```
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        { 
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Users where UserID = @id", conn);

        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

        ds = new DataSet();

        da.SelectCommand = selectCommand;

        da.Fill(ds);

        }
```

I see most of the examples use sqlcommandbuilder or the .delete() or .remove() methods. What is the difference if I do all crud operations this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consequence is confusion, and you're doubling down on confusion here:

- The customary way of deleting records is to use `ExecuteNonQuery`.
- The method exists to delete rows but you've named the command `selectCommand`. This obfuscates the intent of the method. You should strive to be obvious in your code, not devious.

Follow the custom. Be kind to the developers who may have to maintain your code. That includes you, if you have to open it up a few months after you've written it. If it's another developer, they'll curse you as a fool and you'll have a hard time defending yourself with code like this.

A side benefit of using `ExecuteNonQuery` is that it will return the number of rows deleted, so it allows you to verify the delete if you need to:

```
 using (conn = new SqlConnection(cs)) { 
    SqlCommand deleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Users where UserID = @id", conn);
    deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    conn.Open();
    int rowsDeleted = deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (rowsDeleted != 1) {
        // something unexpected happened
    }
}
```

I'm not saying you should follow custom for custom's sake. If you have a breakthrough innovation by all means employ it, but this doesn't qualify as an innovation.

Comment: The `conn.Close()` is not recommended when using the connection in a `using` block since it may result in the connection object being disposed twice. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Winney rightly pointed (in comments) better not complicating things by using DataSet/DataAdapter where it is not required.

You can explore [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your case.

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{ 
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Users where UserID = @id", conn);
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    selectCommand.Connection.Open();
    selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();          
}
```